# How to add "enter to search" option?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add that when I press "enter" in the search form, it will search, and not only when I click search button:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('#webq_search_submit').click(function() {    
        //code
    }); 
    jQuery('#webq_txt_search').click(function(){  

        jQuery('#webq_txt_search').css("border", "none");
    });   
});
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code.

Comment: You must associate the "enter button press" to a field, so you can tell the event to fire when "enter" is pressed and focus is on that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('#webq_txt_search').on('keypress',function(e){

   if (e.keyCode === 13){
        console.log('enter detected');
   }
   // jQuery('#webq_txt_search').css("border", "none");
}));
```

Use if using this search inside form

$("form").submit(function() { return false; });

Comment: Thanks, it worked, BUT when i press "enter" it also refresh the page :/ what can i do?

Comment: if search is inside form then use

$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() { return false; });
});

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a input[type=submit] html tag, even if hidden with css it can handle the enter keypress.

Answer (score 0):

if you using a form element wich contains a submit button (even hidden), you can bind on the original browser submit event like this.

```
   jQuery('form#cour_form_element').on('submit',function(){
         //do your search
    });
```